# How do I figure out the meaning of a error code when doing linux kernel development?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, runtime-error

I am currently doing some linux kernel development.  I get an error code when invoking crypto_akcipher_encrypt.  The error code I am getting is -75.  I am wondering how to figure out what that error code means.

I have tried to grep for the error code, but nothing is showing up.

Here is my source code:

```
static int __init ak_test_init(void) {
    int error;
    struct crypto_akcipher the_tfm;
    struct scatterlist sg_in, sg_out;
    struct akcipher_request* ak_req;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Begin Testing Asymmetric Cipher API");
    ak_req = init_key(&the_tfm, public_key, 270, 1);

    printk(KERN_INFO "Public Key Initialized!");

    sg_init_one(&sg_in, plain_text, 13);
    sg_init_one(&sg_out, encrypted, 100);

    printk(KERN_INFO "Scatter List Initialized");

    akcipher_request_set_crypt(ak_req, &sg_in, &sg_out, 13, 100);

    printk(KERN_INFO "Set Crypt");

    error = crypto_akcipher_encrypt(ak_req);

    printk(KERN_INFO "Error Code %d", error);

    if(error) {
         printk(KERN_INFO "Error Encrypting!");
    }
    else {
         printk("Cipher Text:\n");
         hexdump(encrypted, 13);
   }

   printk(KERN_INFO "End Asymmetric Key Test.");
   return 0;    // Non-zero return means that the module couldn't be loaded.
```

}

Anyone know how I can go about finding what the error code means?

Comment: It's often the negative of a conventional `errno` value.  So `strerror(75)` might tell you (as run in an ordinary user-mode program, that is).  Or you might be able to find it in one of the `errno.h` files.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.2/source/crypto/rsa.c#L96

Comment: If doing kernel programming you won't get around diving into the kernel's source code.

Comment: @jxh Yes, I suspected it was an EOVERFLOW, and that confirms it.  I was able to fix it by increasing the destination buffer size.  The only problem now is the data is not being encrypted.